# How does the JSON Scehma Validation work in Rest Assured?

Tags: json, jsonschema, rest-assured, json-schema-validator

I am trying to validate a Response JSON with a Schema.
Even on trying to validate a response with wrong Schema the test case is passing.

JSON Response:

```
[
    {
        "downlinkBytes": 478,
        "firstProcessTime": {
            "millisSinceEpoch": 1501113600000,
            "daysSinceEpoch": 17374,
            "month": 7,
            "year": 2017,
            "day": 27
        },
        "sliceMonth": 5,
        "sliceYear": 2017,
        "totalBytes": 548,
        "updatedProcessTime": {
            "millisSinceEpoch": 1514764800000,
            "daysSinceEpoch": 17532,
            "month": 1,
            "year": 2018,
            "day": 1
        },
        "uplinkBytes": 54,
        "key": {
            "slicePeriod": {
                "millisSinceEpoch": 1493596800000,
                "daysSinceEpoch": 17287,
                "month": 5,
                "year": 2017,
                "day": 1
            },
            "serviceProvider": "ABC"
        }
    }
]
```

JSON Schema:

```
{
    "type" : "array",
    "items" : {
        "downlinkBytes" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
        "firstProcessTime" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
                "millisSinceEpoch" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
                "daysSinceEpoch" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
                "month" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
                "year"  : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
                "day" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true}
            }
        },
        "sliceMonth" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
        "sliceYear" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
        "totalBytes" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
        "updatedProcessTime" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
                "millisSinceEpoch" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
                "daysSinceEpoch" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
                "month" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
                "year"  : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
                "day" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true}
            }
        },
        "uplinkBytes" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
        "key" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
                "server_imsi" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
                "millisSinceEpoch" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
                "daysSinceEpoch" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
                "month" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
                "year"  : {"type" : "number", "required" : true},
                "day" : {"type" : "number", "required" : true}
            }
        },
        "serviceProvider" : {"type" : "string", "required" : true}
    }
}
```

I am expecting an error here because the response doesn't contain served_imsi value which is required. But the test is passing.

```
Response response = RestAssured.given().when().get(getURL);
response.then().statusCode(Numbers.TWO_HUNDRED);
response.then().assertThat().body(JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("Schema.json"));
```

Comment: On debug, i see the below error: The content to match the given JSON schema.
warning: the following keywords are unknown and will be ignored: [downlinkBytes, firstProcessTime, key, serviceProvider, sliceMonth, sliceYear, totalBytes, updatedProcessTime, uplinkBytes]
    level: "warning"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"file:/D:/Workspaces/Testing/target/classes/Schema/Schema.json#","pointer":"/items"}
    domain: "syntax"
    ignored: ["downlinkBytes","firstProcessTime","key","serviceProvider","sliceMonth","sliceYear","totalBytes","updatedProcessTime","uplinkBytes"]

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. The reason it was not throwing an error was because there was no id key mentioned in the Schema.

Updated Schema:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"definitions": {

},
"id": "http://localhost:8080/xxx/abc/monthly/ABC/5/2017",
"items": {
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "id": "/items",
    "properties": {
        "downlinkBytes": {
            "id": "/items/properties/downlinkBytes",
            "type": "number"
        },
        "firstProcessTime": {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "id": "/items/properties/firstProcessTime",
            "properties": {
                "day": {
                    "id": "/items/properties/firstProcessTime/properties/day",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "daysSinceEpoch": {
                    "id": "/items/properties/firstProcessTime/properties/daysSinceEpoch",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "millisSinceEpoch": {
                    "id": "/items/properties/firstProcessTime/properties/millisSinceEpoch",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "month": {
                    "id": "/items/properties/firstProcessTime/properties/month",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "year": {
                    "id": "/items/properties/firstProcessTime/properties/year",
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "month",
                "year",
                "day",
                "daysSinceEpoch",
                "millisSinceEpoch"
            ],
            "type": "object"
        },
        "key": {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "id": "/items/properties/key",
            "properties": {
                "serviceProvider": {
                    "id": "/items/properties/key/properties/serviceProvider",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "slicePeriod": {
                    "additionalProperties": false,
                    "id": "/items/properties/key/properties/slicePeriod",
                    "properties": {
                        "day": {
                            "id": "/items/properties/key/properties/slicePeriod/properties/day",
                            "type": "number"
                        },
                        "daysSinceEpoch": {
                            "id": "/items/properties/key/properties/slicePeriod/properties/daysSinceEpoch",
                            "type": "number"
                        },
                        "millisSinceEpoch": {
                            "id": "/items/properties/key/properties/slicePeriod/properties/millisSinceEpoch",
                            "type": "number"
                        },
                        "month": {
                            "id": "/items/properties/key/properties/slicePeriod/properties/month",
                            "type": "number"
                        },
                        "year": {
                            "id": "/items/properties/key/properties/slicePeriod/properties/year",
                            "type": "number"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "month",
                        "year",
                        "day",
                        "daysSinceEpoch",
                        "millisSinceEpoch"
                    ],
                    "type": "object"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "serviceProvider",
                "slicePeriod"
            ],
            "type": "object"
        },
        "sliceMonth": {
            "id": "/items/properties/sliceMonth",
            "type": "number"
        },
        "sliceYear": {
            "id": "/items/properties/sliceYear",
            "type": "number"
        },
        "totalBytes": {
            "id": "/items/properties/totalBytes",
            "type": "number"
        },
        "updatedProcessTime": {
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "id": "/items/properties/updatedProcessTime",
            "properties": {
                "day": {
                    "id": "/items/properties/updatedProcessTime/properties/day",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "daysSinceEpoch": {
                    "id": "/items/properties/updatedProcessTime/properties/daysSinceEpoch",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "millisSinceEpoch": {
                    "id": "/items/properties/updatedProcessTime/properties/millisSinceEpoch",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "month": {
                    "id": "/items/properties/updatedProcessTime/properties/month",
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "year": {
                    "id": "/items/properties/updatedProcessTime/properties/year",
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "month",
                "year",
                "day",
                "daysSinceEpoch",
                "millisSinceEpoch"
            ],
            "type": "object"
        },
        "uplinkBytes": {
            "id": "/items/properties/uplinkBytes",
            "type": "number"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "key",
        "totalBytes",
        "updatedProcessTime",
        "uplinkBytes",
        "sliceMonth",
        "downlinkBytes",
        "sliceYear",
        "firstProcessTime"
    ],
    "type": "object"
},
"type": "array"
```

}

It validates properly now. :)

Links that helped:

http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/

https://jsonschema.net/#/editor